# Как найти наименьший элемент в массиве

Tags: java

Вот код

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] array = new int[3][3];
        int max = 9;
        array[0][0] = 1;
        array[0][1] = 2;
        array[0][2] = 3;
        array[1][0] = 4;
        array[1][1] = 5;
        array[1][2] = 6;
        array[2][0] = 7;
        array[2][1] = 8;
        array[2][2] = 9;
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++){
                System.out.print(array[i] [j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: По-разному можно. Можно придумать самому, как реализовать. Можно почитать что-нибудь на эту тему, например вот ссылка из гугла: https://urok.1sept.ru/articles/670033

Comment: Ну у вас же есть большая часть кода, остаётся только сравнение добавить

Comment: А что у вас не получается?

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению, я не знакома с java, но это можно сделать как-то так:

```
int min = array[0][0];
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++){
        if (min > array[i][j]) {min = array[i][j];}
    }
}
System.out.print(min);
```